# Angular - factory should return value from 3rd party callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest, callback

I am currently trying to write an angular service to handle a third party API. The API object handles everything. You just create the object, call a function on it, and get a payload. When I step through the service function in the debugger, I can see the JSON response inside the findRole function, but then it errors out on:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Any ideas of how to make this work?

## Module

```
var angular = require('angular'),
    govtracksvc = require('./rep.service'),
    Rep = require('./Rep'),
    govtrack = require('govtrack-node');

angular.module('RepresentativeApp', [])
    .value('govtrack', govtrack)
    .factory('govtracksvc', govtracksvc)
    .controller('Rep', Rep);

module.exports = angular.module('RepresentativeApp');
```

## Controller

```
module.exports = function Rep (govtracksvc) {
    var rep = this;
    rep.list = govtracksvc.findRole(rep.govtrack);
};
```

## Service

```
module.exports = function govtracksvc(govtrack) {
    var rep = this;
    var data = {};
    govtrack.findRole({current: true}, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err: ', err);
        }
        return res;
    }).then(function (res) {
        data = res.objects;
    });
    return data;
};
```

Here is the endpoint, should anyone want to see the data: https://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/role/?current=true

Comment: Can you share govtrack.findRole implementation. The issue might be there

Comment: @iLoveJS It is 3rd party code, and as I mentioned, I can see the response in the debugger. If I inspect the response before it hits the .then() line, the package is visible.

Comment: @iLoveJS in case this helps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/govtrack-node

Comment: if there is no `then` use `$q` to create promise

Comment: I think it should be easier than having to use $q. At least that is what I am hoping, but you make an interesting point, @charlietfl .then() is a function for a Promise object....

Comment: you can add callback to your service method also

Comment: Argh. JS Promise objects are not supported by IE at all.

Comment: I think you are right about $q now, actually, after doing some reading.

Comment: Using a callback can be a possible solution on cross-browser level.

Comment: The problem seems to be that Angular doesn't recognize the API call in order to track its success or failure. I am wondering if just writing my own HTTP request would be easier. Certainly would not have taken me this long. It is just a bummer, because this is handily namespaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code sample using callback, see if it suits your need:
**Module**

```
var angular = require('angular'),
govtracksvc = require('./rep.service'),
Rep = require('./Rep'),
govtrack = require('govtrack-node');

angular.module('RepresentativeApp', [])
    .value('govtrack', govtrack)
    .factory('govtracksvc', govtracksvc)
    .controller('Rep', Rep);

module.exports = angular.module('RepresentativeApp');
```

**Controller**

```
module.exports = function Rep (govtracksvc, $scope) {
    var rep = this;
    govtracksvc.findRole(rep.govtrack, function(result){
        rep.list = result;
        if(!$scope.$$phase){
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
};
```

**Service**

```
module.exports = function govtracksvc(govtrack, callback) {
var rep = this;
govtrack.findRole({current: true}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err: ', err);
        return {};
      }
    return res.objects;
    });
};
```

Comment: What is this? if(!$scope.$$phase){
            $scope.$apply();
        }

Comment: Sometimes, while making Async calls, the angular scope apply/refresh doesn't happen, so in that case this code does that manually for you, so that you get the instant effect on the UI. Here is a famous blog about that: http://ruoyusun.com/2013/05/25/things-i-wish-i-were-told-about-angular-js.html

Comment: I went with $q, but I'm giving you credit for the answer since your answer paved the way.

Comment: Thanks, but I have found $q not to be compatible in IEs, But if it works for you, sure thats the best angular way to go through.